# Implementing observer pattern with events

Tags: c#, events, observer-pattern

I am working on a Silverlight application where I made excessive use of the observer pattern. In my implementation I have created two interfaces `IObservable<T>` and `IObserver<T>`. The former contains methods to attach and detach observers to the observable. The latter has a method `Notify(IObservable<T> observable, ...)` that is called by the observable passing itself as parameter via `observer.Notify(this, ...)` when the observable has changed its state.

Now I have stumbled upon "events" and for me it seems pretty much as if this were an implementation of the observer pattern, just with delegates instead of the aforementioned `Notify`-method. **Is that right?**

I do not know much about delegates and do not want to spend hours on rewriting my code just to end up with code that does the same thing as it already does. On the other hand events might be superior to the interface-based observer pattern. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Events are an implementation of the *observer pattern*.

An event is implemented as a list of methods to be called when the vent is raised.

Delegates are method references: in contrast to Java, C# offers a way to refer to a method.

It's not a priori better to use events than implement the observer pattern oneself. But events offer a quite generic way to do it, and are in many cases highly optimized for the task, thus give a more efficient and convenient way organize this.

A delegate is defined by the *signature* of the expected method. For instance with:

```
public delegate void FooMethod (Bar x, Baz y);
```

You define a delegate for `void` methods given a `Bar` and a `Baz`. So if you have an instance of the following class:

```
public class Qux {

    public void Method (Bar x, Baz y) {
        //do something
        return null;
    }

}
```

Then you can refer to the method:

```
Qux q = new Qux();
FooMethod fm = q.Method;
```

An `event` is thus a list of `delegate`s with the same signature:

You define an event as:

```
private event FooMethod SomeEvent;
```

You can add `delegate`s (listeners) by using the `+=` operator:

```
SomeEvent += q.Method;
```

remove the delegate by the `-=` operator and call the event with:

```
SomeEvent(new Bar(), new Baz());
```

As if you call a single method that does the dispatching.

By calling the `event`, all the registered `delegate`s will be called, in the order of registration.

> **Note**: By calling `SomeEvent(new Bar(), new Baz());` this does not mean every delegate receives `new` instances: the instances are constructed first and *shared* over all delegate calls.

**Conclusion**: I think the C# designers did a good job introducing observer patterns since the programmer is no longer responsible to program it correctly his/herself. Furthermore the events are easy to understand and use convenient syntax. In special situations however programmers can be required to implement an *observer* him/herself. But these are very rare occasions.

Comment: Right now my observables have a method NotifyAll() that loops through the attached observers and calls its Notify-method. This is equivalent to SomeEvent(new Bar(), New Baz()). Later I will need to notify only certain observers and this decision I'll have to fell on runtime. Is there a way to achieve it with events?

Comment: @JCvanDamme: indeed. The advantage is thus that the programmer doesn't need to make sure such methods are implemented correctly which is of course always nice. As they say: Software design is the study on how to make systems fail proof. The universe is an experiment to produce bigger fools. And currently the universe is winning :P.

Comment: (EDIT: With 'it' I mean something like 'if (observer B is attached) then do not notify observer A who is also attached')

Comment: @JCvanDamme: no that is not implemented. IN that case, you can create for instance two events, register `A` and `B` to both and only `B` to the second, and depending on the content, fire one of the two events. Is is in many cases bad practice to attach too much responsibility to the `IObservable<T>`.

Comment: `to notify only certain observers` - this is one of the reasons why standard event have `sender` as a parameter of event handler. In `C#` filtering (not processing event for certain subscribers) is a job of subscriber himself. All event handlers are called when event is raised (called), but each can make own decision whenever to run or not to run.

Comment: @Sinatr: Sure, but sometimes the situation can be more complicated. Sometimes the `IObservable<T>` has more information, and thus knows who to concact (private information).

Comment: I offer to read comparison of different implementations of Observer Pattern on this link: https://github.com/millermedeiros/js-signals/wiki/Comparison-between-different-Observer-Pattern-implementations