# Difference between "observer" vs. "notify" (in property block) vs. "observers" vs. "listeners" in Polymer

Tags: javascript, html, dom, polymer, dom-events

I'm trying to understand the difference between "observer" vs. "notify" in Polymer properties block, and also how they differ from "observers" and "listeners". The online documentation does not seem to elaborate on them.

Could someone explain this to me?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

- **notify** fires an event to notify parents about changed properties
- **observer** is a function called when a property changes
- **listeners** is an event handler called when a specific event was recieved

Comment: Observer is a pattern. To implement it every observer object needs to have, say `update(...)` method. They are registering themselves to the Subject and Subject is calling observer's update method. Event listener is working on an object like `Subject` in observer pattern. The registerars are registering their function to the event emitter object's event name. Do you think that these two (event emitter and observer) same?

Comment: I don't fully understand the question. Observer pattern and Subject are quite  similar. I'm not sure what you mean exactly with "event emitter" and "observer".

Comment: You are right `Subject` - `Observer` are in observer pattern. I'm just asking event emitter/listener is same with subject/observer. If so, event emitter is another form of Observer pattern?

Comment: What "event emitter"? From where?

Comment: Ok, I found a link which explains what I thought. https://stackoverflow.com/a/27507539/104085